# Issues with $filter('limitTo') in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Having issues with using the limitTo filter through javascript

The [angularjs docs for limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) state that the filter is to be used in the following way:

```
$filter('limitTo')(input, limit, begin)
```

please note the begin parameter is optional.

Following from the above I did the following:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope,$filter) {
   $scope.numbers =[1,2,4,1,8,11,345,123,908,223,4646,132,24,43,3,76,432,1];
   $filter('limitTo')($scope.numbers, 3);   
}

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 {{numbers}}
</div>
```

I expect my output to be

```
[1,2,4]
```

Yet the whole array was shown meaning the limitTo filter didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23827/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular's `$filter` doesn't modify the original array, so you have to do it like this:

```
$scope.filteredArray = $filter('limitTo')($scope.numbers, 3);
```

Comment: This works and I reckon an example in their docs to illustrate this would have been useful.

Comment: `Creates a new array or string containing only a specified number of elements.` It says so in the first sentence on the page ;)

Comment: My bad... I often just skip to the examples. Won't do that again.